# Adding classes to individual list items in a site map

Tags: 7, theming

I am using the [Site Map](http://drupal.org/project/site_map) module in my site but I need to style my list items individually. Is there a way to add a different class to each list item in the site map?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) blocks on a basic page for building a sitemap - it gives more control over the menu order, title display, etc. (unless, of course, you need the RSS feed icons in the sitemap - then the Sitemap module is more useful.) With Menu Block, you get a unique mlid class for each list item.